# Passing a Variable to Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

Trying to figure out how to pass a variable to fabric but having issues:

```
def installpatch(install):
sudo("apt-get install %s") % install
```

However when passing trying to execute this via CLI, it shows up as the below:

```
user@linux: fab installpatch:vi
Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 100 while executing!
Requested: apt-get install %s
Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:' /bin/bash -l -c "apt-get install %s"
```

Entering it as

```
fab installpatch:'vi'
```

makes no difference. Any suggestions? I'm assuming I'm just missing something super simple.

Goal: Be able to create a fabric command that allows me to pass a variable/name to it to install a specific piece of software on multiple PCs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo(("apt-get install %s") % install)
```

or

```
sudo("apt-get install {}".format(install))
```

The % operator in your question works only when combined with a string.

Comment: You don't need the inner parens in the  first one.

Comment: Used the first one and it worked like a charm thanks!